# Can I still play games that have been removed from Steam?

Tags: steam

As Steam gets more remastered titles (e.g. Metro Redux, Sleeping Dogs, etc.), their older counterparts are no longer available to buy on Steam (presumably to entice people to actually buy the remastered titles).

Now, these "old" versions of the games are in my library, but will they remain there? Will I still be able to play these games in the future (as I have no intention of buying the remastered versions)?

Comment: We have no idea what Valve will do in the future.  Currently, yes, you can, but we can make no guarantee that that's how they will continue to do so.

Comment: "Vote to close because the question is about unreleased or illegal content." Hmm... Not too sure about that one.

Comment: You're asking us what Valve is going to do in the future.  We don't know.  If you want to ask about how it works now, that, we can answer.

Comment: @Frank How do I know that you don't know? Valve may well have publicly commented on this, and I have not seen their comment, so it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: If Valve has commented on the situation or not doesn't matter.  If it requires privileged information in order to answer, we don't allow those questions, because Arqade isn't a news site.  Like I said; if you want to ask how it works *today*, that, we can answer.  Asking us how it will work in the future is completely off-topic.

Comment: @Frank So, if I'm asking a question about how Steam currently works, it's ok, but if I ask a question about how Steam will work (assuming that this info has already been released) it's off-topic? Since when does time make a difference? I'm asking the question under the assumption that Steam has, in fact, commented on this, but I can't find it.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  In order for us to be able to answer how it will work in the future, all we have to go off of is what the developer says.  And what they say is quite often not true.  Xbone always online, anyone?  Without having something available for us to test and verify, all we're doing is repeating what's already been said.  It also starts gathering rumors and speculation, which are exactly the things we don't want.  Arqade's not a news site, so we've determined that doing so isn't in our expertise.  Present = good.  Future = bad.

Comment: @Frank Any policy for any company can change at any point in time.  Steam has a policy regarding being able to access purchased games that have been removed, this question *is* answerable.  If the policy changes in the future, then this question will need a new answer regarding the new policy.  It's no different than when game mechanics change after patches.

Comment: @cimmanon Except we can *test* game mechanics.  We *can't* test word of mouth. Therein lies the critical difference.  One plays to our expertise, the other reduces us to parroting what developers have said. Arqade is not a news site.  If it takes privileged information to answer, we don't allow those questions.

Comment: There have been games removed from the store that people have bought. There is nothing speculative, unreleased or illegal here. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @3ventic He is specifically asking if this will continue in this manner in the future.  That's *exactly* what the future speculation close reason is for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can.

If you have bought a game on steam that is not available for purchase anymore, you will be able to download and play the game anyway. The game is still available on steam, just not for purchase.
Someone could even gift you a game that's not available for sale anymore, assuming they had it in their inventory before it got pulled from the store.

Comment: I don't have a source for this information, but there are multiple games that have been removed from the steam store in past and people are still able to download and play them if they own the game.

Comment: I purchased an indie game a few years ago and shortly afterwards the developers went out of business.  Steam removed the game for sale, but I was able to continue playing it and unlock achievements for it.  So I can certainly confirm this is the case.

Comment: The old Deus Ex: Human Revolution was removed from the store in favor of the Director's Cut version, and I can still play the old version. It appears in my inventory like any other game.

Answer (score -5):

Yes You Can,but you will have to know the number for example: steam://install/(number) then copy and paste it in a chat and it will download for another example: steam://install/427920 (FNAF WORLD)

Hope This Helped

Comment: The question doesn't ask about downloading games that were removed from the store, but playing games that were previously bought and then removed. Not to mention, you're adding nothing that wasn't already said 19 months ago.